# Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'group of methods' and 'string' in c#

Tags: c#, upload

I have problem with this code for upload in c#.

I need prevent upload multiple duplicate name file.

The error is :

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'group of methods'
>   and 'string'

What's the problem ?

My code below, thank you in advance.

```
DirectoryInfo objDir =
    new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("\\images\\"));

string sFileName = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
string sFileExt = Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName);

FileInfo[] objFI =
    objDir.GetFiles(sFileName.Replace(sFileExt, "") + ".*");

if (objFI.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in objFI)
    {
        string sFileName1 = objFI[0].Name;
        string sFileExt1 = Path.GetExtension < (objFI[0].Name); // LINE ERROR

        if (sFileName1.Replace(sFileExt1, "") ==
                sFileName.Replace(sFileExt, ""))
        {
            iFailedCnt += 1;        // NOT ALLOWING DUPLICATE.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT #1**

```
protected void Upload_Files(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileUpload.HasFile)     // CHECK IF ANY FILE HAS BEEN SELECTED.
        {
            int iUploadedCnt = 0;
            int iFailedCnt = 0;
            HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            lblFileList.Text = "Select <b>" + hfc.Count + "</b> file(s)";

            if (hfc.Count <= 10)    // 10 FILES RESTRICTION.
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= hfc.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        if (!File.Exists(Server.MapPath("\\images\\") + 
                            Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)))
                        {
                            DirectoryInfo objDir = 
                                new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("\\images\\"));

                            string sFileName = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                            string sFileExt = Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName);

                            // CHECK FOR DUPLICATE FILES.
                            FileInfo[] objFI = 
                                objDir.GetFiles(sFileName.Replace(sFileExt, "") + ".*");

                            if (objFI.Length > 0)
                            {
                                // CHECK IF FILE WITH THE SAME NAME EXISTS 
                                    (IGNORING THE EXTENTIONS).
                                foreach (FileInfo file in objFI)
                                {
                                    string sFileName1 = objFI[0].Name;
                                    string sFileExt1 = Path.GetExtension(objFI[0].Name);

                                    if (sFileName1.Replace(sFileExt1, "") == 
                                            sFileName.Replace(sFileExt, ""))
                                    {
                                        iFailedCnt += 1;        // NOT ALLOWING DUPLICATE.
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // SAVE THE FILE IN A FOLDER.
                                hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("\\images\\") + 
                                    Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                                iUploadedCnt += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                lblUploadStatus.Text = "<b>" + iUploadedCnt + "</b> file(s) Uploaded.";
                lblFailedStatus.Text = "<b>" + iFailedCnt + 
                    "</b> duplicate file(s) could not be uploaded.";
            }
            else lblUploadStatus.Text = "Max. 10 files allowed.";
        }
        else lblUploadStatus.Text = "No files selected.";
    }
```

Comment: What should `Path.GetExtension < (objFI[0].Name)` do? As far as I am concerned, this is just a typo...

Comment: by the way you do not need this verification `if (objFI.Length > 0)`

Comment: It is just a typo, there is a < before the argument. However I wish to say that  _Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension_ could simplify your code a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get extension is a function and you have `<` between it and its `()`

Replace this:

```
string sFileExt1 = Path.GetExtension < (objFI[0].Name);
```

With:

```
string sFileExt1 = Path.GetExtension(objFI[0].Name);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, now I don't have error but on case duplicate files the files are not uploaded but the count of files not uploaded is always 0. Please see **EDIT #1** in my first question.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq That's another question. [Chameleon questions are discouraged on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). See point #4 in the link.

Comment: For that debug it and see where your logic fails to work.  Also check out Steve's comment to make code cleaner.